# specify network interface for kubesystem pods

Tags: networking, virtualbox, kubernetes

I've created a virtual kubernetes cluster using vagrant boxes.  All my boxes have 2 network interfaces

```
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 02:1d:76:b3:3c:fe brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global enp0s3
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::1d:76ff:feb3:3cfe/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:35:39:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.70.11/24 brd 192.168.70.255 scope global enp0s8
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe35:399f/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

enp0s3 is created by default and has the same ip address on all the boxes.  Apparently this is a virtual box thing https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/6456 .  I added the enp0s8 interface as a private network to allow my boxes to talk to each other, this one has a different IP on each box so I want to use it for kubernetes.

When I set up my cluster I used this command which allowed me to create the cluster on the first node and join the second node

```
$ kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.70.11 --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

The problem is all the kube-system pods are still using the enp0s3 interface

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system get pods -owide
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP           NODE
coredns-78fcdf6894-8tpnc         1/1       Running   0          11m       10.244.0.2   node-1
coredns-78fcdf6894-tbqxk         1/1       Running   0          11m       10.244.0.3   node-1
etcd-node-1                      1/1       Running   0          10m       10.0.2.15    node-1
kube-apiserver-node-1            1/1       Running   0          10m       10.0.2.15    node-1
kube-controller-manager-node-1   1/1       Running   0          10m       10.0.2.15    node-1
kube-flannel-ds-5wm74            1/1       Running   0          11m       10.0.2.15    node-2
kube-flannel-ds-wx77l            1/1       Running   0          11m       10.0.2.15    node-1
kube-proxy-gmst8                 1/1       Running   0          11m       10.0.2.15    node-2
kube-proxy-sbqqs                 1/1       Running   0          11m       10.0.2.15    node-1
kube-scheduler-node-1            1/1       Running   0          10m       10.0.2.15    node-1
```

I'd like to force kubernetes to use enp0s8 exclusively.  Is there anyway to do that without removing the the enp0s3 interface?

This is what the nodes look like

```
$ kubectl get nodes -owide
NAME      STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
node-1    Ready     master    4m        v1.11.2   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS   4.4.0-134-generic   docker://17.3.2
node-2    Ready     <none>    3m        v1.11.2   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS   4.4.0-134-generic   docker://17.3.2
```

And this is the version info

```
$ sudo KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.2", GitCommit:"bb9ffb1654d4a729bb4cec18ff088eacc153c239", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-07T23:17:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.2", GitCommit:"bb9ffb1654d4a729bb4cec18ff088eacc153c239", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-07T23:08:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Could you provide here version of Kubernetes and output of `kubectl get nodes -o wide`?

Comment: I've added this info to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue on GitHub related to your problem: [kubelet reports wrong IP address #44702](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44702)

At the end of the discussion, [yujuhong](https://github.com/yujuhong) [explained](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44702#issuecomment-299548622) why this happens:

> kubelet uses the [IP address reported by the cloud provider](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.11/pkg/kubelet/kubelet_node_status.go#L448) if it exists, or the first non-loopback ipv4 address ([code here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.11/pkg/kubelet/kubelet_node_status.go#L553)) if there is no cloud provider. In addition, it could be overwritten by kubelet flags.

I've updated the links in the quote to v1.11. Here what is mentioned in the [code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.11/pkg/kubelet/kubelet_node_status.go#L553) comments for v1.11:

```
    // 1) Use nodeIP if set
    // 2) If the user has specified an IP to HostnameOverride, use it
    // 3) Lookup the IP from node name by DNS and use the first valid IPv4 address.
    //    If the node does not have a valid IPv4 address, use the first valid IPv6 address.
    // 4) Try to get the IP from the network interface used as default gateway
```

Options of kubelet mentioned in code comments are copied from [kubelet documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/):

> 1. --node-ip string - IP address of the node. If set, kubelet will use this IP address for the node
> 2. --hostname-override string - If non-empty, will use this string as identification instead of the actual hostname.

If we look at the [code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.11/pkg/kubelet/kubelet_node_status.go#L560), we will see that it [expects IPv4 or IPv6](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.10/src/net/ip.go#L646:6) address here:

```
if addr := net.ParseIP(kl.hostname); addr != nil
```

Last two options are not very convenient and reliable to use in your case, so I skipped them.

The first option was also suggested by [dcbw](https://github.com/dcbw) in the [comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44702#issuecomment-302471161) and had positive feedback:

> If you're not using a cloud provider, try modifying the kubelet command-line options to pass "--node-ip=" or setting the NodeIP configuration in the kubelet config yaml file.

Anyway, it is up to you to choose what suits you best.